# C++ code for solving submission series equations

Tags: c++

*I have to write a code to solve the 3 equations mentioned in the code below.The code below seems right to me but the compiler executes the first equation correctly but always gives sum as 0 and 1 respectively for equations 2 and 3. I've tried everything.We are only supposed to use loops,conditions,switch case or functions.Please help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUTI2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjS5r.png)

Comment: Hi! Will you please edit the question to include the code text inline? It will be easier to help if we can copy/paste the code. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please check out the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and carefully read the [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Posting images of code is generally frowned upon, and takes more work than simply copy/pasting the code itself. If possible, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue you are having so that someone may be able to help you.

Comment: None of those are equations, and can't really be "solved". They are just sums.

Comment: Here's something that baffles me greatly: It is way more work to take screenshots and paste those in instead of text. Why didn't you paste text, when it's both *easier* and also the right thing to do?

Comment: Unslander well I am totally new to this site.I couldn't properly inline the code or whatever. So I had to resort to posting the ss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at this code, I can see a couple of issues related to data types. The terms you are adding to the sum in both problems 2 and 3 are not going to be whole numbers, yet in:

```
sum += i/(i+1);
sum += 1/i;
```

Since `i` is an **integer**, dividing `i` by `i+1` is interpreted as being integer division which should return a whole number (i.e. the result will be rounded). In most case, the expression will round to zero (except when `i=1` in the third problem).

To fix this, we must cast these values to `float` before doing math on them:

```
sum += (float)(i) / (float)(i+1);
sum += 1.0/(float)(i);
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I didn't copy paste the code bec I couldn't figure out the inline thing. I just joined this site yesterday. So I had to posting ss.

Comment: Great! If this answer is helpful or what you were looking for, please go ahead and accept or upvote it :). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers